# Windows (all versions): check/uncheck multiple options in contextual menu without multiplying right-clicks?

Tags: windows, menu, customization, right-click

I've had this question for years, but never got round to asking it out loud: sometimes, we need to check or uncheck several items in a contextual menu (for example, right-click on the menu bar in Windows to add/remove the "Show destkop" option AND add/remove the search bar AND add/remove the Tasks icon), and we have to right-click several times in a row, which is time-consuming and clumsy.

Is there a way to keep the contextual menu open/visible after completing one operation, so you can perform another, until you're done?

I've tried all the key combinations I could think of (via the shift, ctrl, alt keys, for example), without success...

Answer (score 0):

No, a normal menu does not support this.

It does work in the Start Menu in some Windows versions but those menus are actually custom-draw toolbars, not menus.

Comment: Damn... That's too bad, because it could come in handy every once in a while.